# Why isn't express's res.render called inside the PUT method?

Tags: express, fetch, ejs, render, put

I have an express app with ejs view engine.
In the ejs template, I have a button with an onClick event to trigger a fetch request:

```
<button class="remove-btn" onclick="removeGroceryItem('<%= index %>')" >Remove</button>
```

the fetch function

```
function removeGroceryItem (id) {
    fetch('/', {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ groceryItem: id })
    })
    .then((value)=> console.log(value))
    .catch((e)=>console.error(e))
}
```

The express app route handler:

```
/* PUT grocery list*/
app.put('/', function(req, res, next) {
  groceryItemsContainer.splice(Number.parseInt(req.body.groceryItem), 1)
  res.render('index', { 
    title: 'Express Grocery List App',
    notification: 'removed',
    groceryList: groceryItemsContainer
  })
  res.end();
})
```

The PUT request is received with a status of 200. But the res.render does not seem to be triggered -- why is that??

Comment: Why do you think the `res.render()` isn't called?  What result do you get in the `.then()` or `.catch()` on the `fetch()`?  Did you put a `console.log()` right before and after the `res.render()` to see if they show output?  Do you realize that an Ajax call like `fetch()` just gets data for your Javascript - it does not change the browser page on its own.

Comment: Also, calling `res.end()` after you call `res.render()` is a mistake and an error.  `res.render()` already calls `res.end()` on it's own.  So, please remove the `res.end()`.

Comment: As @jfriend00 pointed out, you call `res.end()` before the `res.render()` has had a chance to do what it needs to do.

Comment: From the console, I see that there was a PUT request made, but there are no GET requests following to get the styles and javascripts. So I doubt res.render has been run.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your comment that you are expecting the result of your `res.render()` to display in the browser.  That is NOT what an Ajax call using `fetch()` does from your browser Javascript.  It ONLY gets the content back to your Javascript.  It does not display anything in the browser.

So, the content you `res.render()` goes back to your Javascript in your web page and the `console.log(value)` you have in your Javascript in the web page should actually be showing the content in the console from the `res.render()`.  If you want that content to display in the browser, then you need to insert that content into the current browser DOM yourself with your own Javascript.

Comment: That makes sense. So if I want to get ejs to re-render the template with the new variables, how should I go about it?

Comment: @EddieLam - If it's the exact same page URL that you just want a fresh, updated copy of, you could have your browser Javascript just refresh the page with `window.location.reload()` which will cause the browser to request the URL again from your server where you can render it anew.  Or, you could send just the newly added content back as the result of the Ajax call and have your Javascript insert just that new content into the current page to generate the same result as a refresh.  In either of these cases, it's not helping you to send the fully rendered page back to your Javascript as now.